# Apply function and sort in MongoDB without MapReduce

Tags: mongodb

I have an interesting problem. I have a working M/R version of this but it's not really a viable solution in a small-scale environment since it's too slow and the query needs to be executed real-time.

I would like to iterate over each element in a collection and score it, sort by descending, limit to top 10 and return the results to the applications.

Here is the function I'd like applied to each document in pseudo code.

```
var score = 0;
foreach(tag in document.Tags) {
    score += someMap[tag];
}
return score;
```

Comment: Are the contents of `someMap` fixed? Or will they change over time, or change per query? If they are fixed and known at the time when the document is being updated, your best bet will be to do the mapping application-side and insert the score directly into the document (i.e. into an array parallel to the `tags`, or as a scalar `score` attribute).

Comment: someMap is generated by the application so it's known. I'm not updating any of the documents, I'm just reading their info and scoring them.

Comment: Would it be possible for the part of the application which is writing documents to insert their scores according to `someMap`?

Comment: someMap is generated before the query is executed and is different all the time. It then needs to query mongo and then score each item and take the top few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `someMap` is changing each time, I don't see any alternative other than to score all the documents and return the highest-scoring ones. Whatever method you adopt for this type of operation, you'll have to consider all the documents in the collection, which is going to be slow, and will become more and more costly as the collection you're scanning grows.

One issue with map reduce is that each `mongod` instance can only run one concurrent map reduce. This is a limitation of the javascript engine, which is single-threaded. Multiple map reduces will be interleaved, but they cannot run concurrently with one another. This means that if you're relying on map reduce for "real-time" uses, that is, if your web page has to run a map reduce to render, you'll eventually hit a limit where page load times become unacceptably slow.

You can work around this by querying all the documents into your application, and doing the scoring, sorting, and limiting in your application code. Queries in MongoDB can run concurrently, unlike map reduce, though of course this means that your application servers will have to do a lot of work.

Finally, if you are willing to wait for MongoDB 2.2 to be released (which should be within a few months), you can use the new [aggregation framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) in place of map reduce. You'll have to massage the `someMap` to generate the correct pipeline steps. Here's an example of what this might look like if `someMap` were `{"a": 5, "b": 2}`:

```
db.runCommand({aggregate: "foo",
    pipeline: [
        {$unwind: "$tags"},
        {$project: {
            tag1score: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$tags", "a"]}, 5, 0]},
            tag2score: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$tags", "b"]}, 3, 0]}}
        },
        {$project: {score: {$add: ["$tag1score", "$tag2score"]}}},
        {$group: {_id: "$_id", score: {$sum: "$score"}}},
        {$sort: {score: -1}},
        {$limit: 10}
    ]})
```

This is a little complicated, and bears explaining:

1. First, we "unwind" the tags array, so that the following steps in the pipeline process documents where "tags" is a scalar -- the value of the tag from the array -- and all the other document fields (notably `_id`) are duplicated for each unwound element.
2. We use a projection operator to convert from tags to named score fields. The `$cond`/`$eq` expression for each roughly means (for the `tag1score` example) "if the value in the document in the 'tags' field id equal to 'a', then return 5 and assign that value to a new field `tag1score`, else return 0 and assign that". This expression would be repeated for each tag/score combination in your `someMap`. At this point in the pipeline, each document will nave N `tagNscore` fields, but at most one of them will have a non-zero value.
3. Next we use another projection operator to create a `score` field whose value is the sum of the `tagNscore` fields in the document.
4. Next we group the documents by their `_id`, and sum up the value of the `score` field from the previous step across all documents in each group.
5. We sort by `score`, descending (i.e. greatest scores first)
6. We limit to only the top 10 scores.

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader how to convert `someMap` into the correct set of projections in step 2, and the correct set of fields to add in step 3.

This is essentially the same set of steps that your application code or map reduce would go through, but has the following distinct advantages: instead of map reduce, the aggregation framework is fully implemented in C++ and is faster and more concurrent than map reduce; and unlike querying all the documents to your application, the aggregation framework works with the data on the server side, saving network load. But like the other two approaches, this will still have to consider each document, and can only limit the result set once the score has been calculated for all of them.

Comment: What a wonderful answer, thanks. Been confused with this for a while. I'm currently doing all the computing on the application as you suggested and once 2.2 comes out I'll follow exactly what you said.

Comment: I should mention -- you can download MongoDB 2.1 or the nightly development releases from http://mongodb.org/downloads. Both 2.1 and the nighties have the aggregation framework already, but are not recommended for production use.

Comment: The docs do mention that aggregation is available in 2.1, we're going to try it out in development.

Comment: Cool, good luck. The 2.1.x series are development releases and are not intended for production use, but please do try it out and share any bugs you find at jira.mongodb.org or questions on the mongodb-user mailing list.